# sortable - start , update , stop events not getting triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

When I am dragging and dropping an item, following code using `sortupdate` gets triggered

```
$('#sortable').sortable().bind('sortupdate', function (event, ui) {
                                            debugger;
                                            //Triggered when the user stopped sorting and the DOM position has changed.
                                        });
```

**BUT**

`start`, `update`, `stop`, `change` events are not getting triggered

That is,

```
$('#sortable').sortable({
        start: function(event, ui) {
            //
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {
            //
        },
        update: function(event, ui) {
            //
        }
    });
```

My goal is to find the *original* and *dropped* position of an item.

**EDIT** (for clear understanding):

In short,

`$('#sortable').sortable().bind('sortupdate' .....` is **working**(triggered)

`$('#sortable').sortable().bind('start' .....` is **not working**(not triggered)
`$('#sortable').sortable().bind('change' .....` is **not working**(not triggered)
`$('#sortable').sortable().bind('update' .....` is **not working**(not triggered)
`$('#sortable').sortable().bind('sort' .....` is **not working**(not triggered)

If possible to get the values of old and new position with `sortupdate` event alone, then also it is ok..My ultimate goal is to find the position of both old and new for an item.

Comment: You are using two different selector: `.sortable`(workable) and `#sortable` (unworkable)

Comment: That is not the case...I changed all those things..

Answer (score 0):

all this event are prefixed with sort so instead of start it becomes sortstart
i have created a fiddle where it will give the message of item moved from and to have a check at

http://jsfiddle.net/p2gethgh/

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
    var from,to;
    $("#sortable").on("sortstart",function(event,ui){
        from = $(this).children().index(ui.item);
    });
    $('#sortable').on('sortdeactivate',function(event,ui) {
        to = $(this).children().index(ui.item);
        alert(ui.item.text()+' moved from '+(from + 1)+' to '+(to + 1));
    });
```

Comment: sortstart is not triggerd

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to bind event to jquery sortable

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
  start: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

OR

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "sortstart", function( event, ui ) {} );
```